# Conditionally create new columns with values dependent on another column

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements, case

Here's a sample dataset.

```
data <- structure(list(well_short = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", 
"A7", "A8", "A9", "A10", "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", 
"B7", "B8", "B9", "B10", "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", 
"C7", "C8", "C9", "C10", "D1", "D2", "D3", "D6", "D7", "D8", 
"E1", "E2", "E3", "E6", "E7", "E8", "F1", "F2", "F3", "F6", "F7", 
"F8", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", 
"C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "D1", "D2", "D3", "E1", "E2", "E3", 
"F1", "F2", "F3"), reporter1 = c("FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", 
"FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", 
"FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", 
"FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", 
"FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", 
"FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", 
"FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", 
"FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", 
"FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM", "FAM"), reporter2 = c("VIC", "VIC", 
"VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", 
"VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", 
"VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", 
"VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", 
"VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", 
"VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", 
"VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", 
"VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC", "VIC"), target1 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "EIF4A2", "EIF4A2", "EIF4A2", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "EIF4A2", "EIF4A2", "EIF4A2", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, "EIF4A2", "EIF4A2", "EIF4A2", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "EIF4A2", 
"EIF4A2", "EIF4A2", NA, NA, NA, "EIF4A2", "EIF4A2", "EIF4A2", 
NA, NA, NA, "EIF4A2", "EIF4A2", "EIF4A2", "FAN1", "FAN1", "FAN1", 
"FAN1", "FAN1", "FAN1", "FAN1", "FAN1", "FAN1", "FAN1", "FAN1", 
"FAN1", "FAN1", "FAN1", "FAN1", "FAN1", "FAN1", "FAN1", "FAN1", 
"FAN1", "FAN1", "FAN1", "FAN1", "FAN1"), target2 = c("GAPDH", 
"GAPDH", "GAPDH", NA, NA, "ATP5B", "ATP5B", "ATP5B", NA, NA, 
"GAPDH", "GAPDH", "GAPDH", NA, NA, "ATP5B", "ATP5B", "ATP5B", 
NA, NA, "GAPDH", "GAPDH", "GAPDH", NA, NA, "ATP5B", "ATP5B", 
"ATP5B", NA, NA, "GAPDH", "GAPDH", "GAPDH", "ATP5B", "ATP5B", 
"ATP5B", "GAPDH", "GAPDH", "GAPDH", "ATP5B", "ATP5B", "ATP5B", 
"GAPDH", "GAPDH", "GAPDH", "ATP5B", "ATP5B", "ATP5B", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), FAM = c(NA, 32.2125244140625, NA, NA, 
NA, 19.1572704315186, 19.4879779815674, 19.4588565826416, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 19.2744884490967, 19.5981330871582, 19.7899913787842, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 20.7965888977051, 20.5950012207031, 
20.6377353668213, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 19.6863594055176, 19.6907558441162, 
19.5781936645508, NA, NA, NA, 19.1406211853027, 19.0943374633789, 
19.3141994476318, NA, NA, NA, 20.8319263458252, 21.4005260467529, 
21.2596740722656, 24.0486278533936, 24.1924858093262, 24.0715713500977, 
37.7646484375, 38.5073165893555, 24.4180793762207, 24.3443660736084, 
24.4652347564697, NA, 38.4971961975098, 25.7233428955078, 26.0083045959473, 
26.009407043457, NA, 36.9249801635742, 24.5213756561279, 24.36501121521, 
24.6891078948975, 23.7516288757324, 24.0062007904053, 24.2912254333496, 
25.8867092132568, 26.408411026001, 26.6710052490234), VIC = c(15.8810548782349, 
15.7486772537231, 15.8836851119995, 28.5859107971191, NA, 17.4370384216309, 
17.8416233062744, 17.8061866760254, NA, NA, 15.9743127822876, 
15.9276437759399, 16.0520458221436, NA, NA, 17.9564743041992, 
17.9996166229248, 18.0147571563721, NA, NA, 16.7361278533936, 
16.876745223999, 16.8310585021973, NA, NA, 19.1682357788086, 
19.2384548187256, 19.2734928131104, 26.6151962280273, NA, 15.9887733459473, 
15.9428396224976, 16.0872936248779, 18.0254516601562, 17.9683456420898, 
18.0603885650635, 16.095287322998, 16.0112743377686, 15.9836187362671, 
17.516263961792, 17.5184440612793, 17.7756538391113, 17.5155448913574, 
17.5042781829834, 17.411714553833, 20.2982234954834, 20.6856136322021, 
20.2655715942383, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-72L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

It looks like this. Each row represents a sample, i.e A1, A2 etc. The machine measures two `reporters`; `FAM` and `VIC`. The trouble is that `FAM` and `VIC` represent different `targets` in each sample.

```
> head(data)
# A tibble: 6 × 7
  well_short reporter1 reporter2 target1 target2   FAM   VIC
  <chr>      <chr>     <chr>     <chr>   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 A1         FAM       VIC       NA      GAPDH    NA    15.9
2 A2         FAM       VIC       NA      GAPDH    32.2  15.7
3 A3         FAM       VIC       NA      GAPDH    NA    15.9
4 A4         FAM       VIC       NA      NA       NA    28.6
5 A5         FAM       VIC       NA      NA       NA    NA  
6 A6         FAM       VIC       EIF4A2  ATP5B    19.2  17.4
```

I want to create a new column for each `target`, like so:

```
# Vector of targets
targets <- sort(unlist(
  lapply(seq(2), function(n) {
    return(unique(data[[get(paste0("targetcol", n))]])[!is.na(unique(data[[get(paste0("targetcol", n))]]))])
  })))

# Add columns to receive target ct values
for(t in targets) {
  data[,t] <- NA
}
```

So the output data frame looks like this:

```
> head(data)
# A tibble: 6 × 11
  well_short reporter1 reporter2 target1 target2   FAM   VIC ATP5B EIF4A2 FAN1  GAPDH
  <chr>      <chr>     <chr>     <chr>   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <lgl> <lgl>  <lgl> <lgl>
1 A1         FAM       VIC       NA      GAPDH    NA    15.9 NA    NA     NA    NA   
2 A2         FAM       VIC       NA      GAPDH    32.2  15.7 NA    NA     NA    NA   
3 A3         FAM       VIC       NA      GAPDH    NA    15.9 NA    NA     NA    NA   
4 A4         FAM       VIC       NA      NA       NA    28.6 NA    NA     NA    NA   
5 A5         FAM       VIC       NA      NA       NA    NA   NA    NA     NA    NA   
6 A6         FAM       VIC       EIF4A2  ATP5B    19.2  17.4 NA    NA     NA    NA
```

I now want to populate the new `target` columns with the relevant measurement from either the `FAM` or `VIC` column.

For example, in the first row `target2` is `GAPDH`. Looking at the `reporter2` column you can see that the `GAPDH` measurement is `VIC`, so I want my new `GAPDH` column to contain the value `15.9`.

Another example is row 6, which has two targets; `EIF4A2` is in `FAM`, and `ATP5B` is in `VIC`, so the resulting values in those two new columns should be `19.2` and `17.4` respectively.

Any ideas how to achieve this in some nice tidy code?

Comment: What's the deal with rows 2 (both FAM & VIC are set while target1 is missing) and 4 (no target is set but VIC is) ? Could modify your output example so it would describe actual expected output, i.e. values set for those new target variables?

Comment: Some samples only have one target assigned, some have two. That's just how the data is I'm afraid. So where no target is set, the result in the new columns should be NA

Answer (score 1):

A `tidyverse` solution:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(target1:target2, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(val = case_match(name, "target1" ~ reporter1, "target2" ~ reporter2) %>%
                 case_match("VIC" ~ VIC, "FAM" ~ FAM)) %>%
  pivot_wider(-name, names_from = value, values_from = val) %>%
  left_join(df, .)

# A tibble: 72 × 11
   well_short reporter1 reporter2 target1 target2   FAM   VIC GAPDH EIF4A2 ATP5B  FAN1
   <chr>      <chr>     <chr>     <chr>   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A1         FAM       VIC       NA      GAPDH    NA    15.9  15.9   NA    NA      NA
 2 A2         FAM       VIC       NA      GAPDH    32.2  15.7  15.7   NA    NA      NA
 3 A3         FAM       VIC       NA      GAPDH    NA    15.9  15.9   NA    NA      NA
 4 A4         FAM       VIC       NA      NA       NA    28.6  NA     NA    NA      NA
 5 A5         FAM       VIC       NA      NA       NA    NA    NA     NA    NA      NA
 6 A6         FAM       VIC       EIF4A2  ATP5B    19.2  17.4  NA     19.2  17.4    NA
 7 A7         FAM       VIC       EIF4A2  ATP5B    19.5  17.8  NA     19.5  17.8    NA
 8 A8         FAM       VIC       EIF4A2  ATP5B    19.5  17.8  NA     19.5  17.8    NA
 9 A9         FAM       VIC       NA      NA       NA    NA    NA     NA    NA      NA
10 A10        FAM       VIC       NA      NA       NA    NA    NA     NA    NA      NA
# … with 62 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data %>%
   rowid_to_column() %>%
   left_join(rename(.,c(FAM1 = 'FAM', FAM2 = 'VIC')) %>%
   pivot_longer(!rowid:well_short, names_to = c(".value", "num"), names_pattern =  "(\\D+)(\\d+)") %>% 
   drop_na() %>% 
   pivot_wider(id_cols = rowid:well_short, names_from = target, values_from = FAM))

Joining with `by = join_by(rowid, well_short)`
# A tibble: 72 × 12
   rowid well_short reporter1 reporter2 target1 target2   FAM   VIC GAPDH EIF4A2 ATP5B  FAN1
   <int> <chr>      <chr>     <chr>     <chr>   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1 A1         FAM       VIC       NA      GAPDH    NA    15.9  15.9   NA    NA      NA
 2     2 A2         FAM       VIC       NA      GAPDH    32.2  15.7  15.7   NA    NA      NA
 3     3 A3         FAM       VIC       NA      GAPDH    NA    15.9  15.9   NA    NA      NA
 4     4 A4         FAM       VIC       NA      NA       NA    28.6  NA     NA    NA      NA
 5     5 A5         FAM       VIC       NA      NA       NA    NA    NA     NA    NA      NA
 6     6 A6         FAM       VIC       EIF4A2  ATP5B    19.2  17.4  NA     19.2  17.4    NA
 7     7 A7         FAM       VIC       EIF4A2  ATP5B    19.5  17.8  NA     19.5  17.8    NA
 8     8 A8         FAM       VIC       EIF4A2  ATP5B    19.5  17.8  NA     19.5  17.8    NA
 9     9 A9         FAM       VIC       NA      NA       NA    NA    NA     NA    NA      NA
10    10 A10        FAM       VIC       NA      NA       NA    NA    NA     NA    NA      NA
# … with 62 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure , please check this:
This is extendable in each direction:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("target"),
               names_to ="name1",
               values_to = "value1") %>%
  pivot_longer(c(FAM, VIC),
               values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
 # na.omit() %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = value1,
              values_from = value,
              values_fn = list) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(GAPDH, EIF4A2, ATP5B, FAN1))
```

```
   well_short reporter1 reporter2 name1   name  `NA`      GAPDH EIF4A2 ATP5B  FAN1
   <chr>      <chr>     <chr>     <chr>   <chr> <list>    <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A1         FAM       VIC       target2 VIC   <NULL>     15.9   NA    NA    NA  
 2 A2         FAM       VIC       target1 FAM   <dbl [1]>  NA     NA    NA    24.2
 3 A2         FAM       VIC       target2 FAM   <dbl [1]>  32.2   NA    NA    NA  
 4 A2         FAM       VIC       target2 VIC   <NULL>     15.7   NA    NA    NA  
 5 A3         FAM       VIC       target2 VIC   <NULL>     15.9   NA    NA    NA  
 6 A6         FAM       VIC       target1 FAM   <NULL>     NA     19.2  NA    NA  
 7 A6         FAM       VIC       target1 VIC   <NULL>     NA     17.4  NA    NA  
 8 A6         FAM       VIC       target2 FAM   <NULL>     NA     NA    19.2  NA  
 9 A6         FAM       VIC       target2 VIC   <NULL>     NA     NA    17.4  NA  
10 A7         FAM       VIC       target1 FAM   <NULL>     NA     19.5  NA    NA  
# … with 103 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```